# Keyboard buffer processed in reverse on high CPU?

Tags: keyboard

Occasionally I keep typing when the computer is responding slowly.
Somehow when it catches up, if several keystrokes are waiting they seem to be processed in reverse? This results in jumbled-up typing, as shown on attached screenshot. I've experienced this on several Ubuntu distros, the latest being 18.10 LTS.

[image: I can almost read this...]